# How to create multiple closed paths from segments in inkscape

Tags: inkscape, svg, path

Is there any comfortable (and accurate) way to convert multiple shapes represented by segments (but rather precisely closed) into shapes?
I want to use files from a CAD system as Basis for a Design. This will include *many* shapes, so I want to avoid processing every single one by hand.

A workaround I know is `Path>Combine` -> `Path>Object to Path` (`Path>Stroke to Path` does exactly the same for me) -> `Path>Break Apart`, but this results in double paths and - more severe - there will be no path at the exact centerline of the original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. Try https://github.com/fablabnbg/inkscape-chain-paths (follow the instructions, too).

Comment: Thank you so much, this does exactly what I was looking for (and actually could have put to use many times before).